# porto theme settings not reflecting magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3.3, porto-theme

I update Porto theme and add all the patches as per the documentation, but none of the existing block or changes is visible. I tried to reinstall but still the same. Please help

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find any solution for this?